# JMeter: Aggregated report not generated using CMDRunner or JMeterPluginsCMD

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I run my .jmx file from command line and I save the metrics to the .jtl file. My .jmx file has the following structure:

- A Thread Group where are my tests in selenium
- A tearDown Thread Group where I have:

  1. A BeanShell Sampler which checks the .jtl file if is not empty if yes, I added a Thread.sleep();
  2. An OS Process Sampler which runs a cmd.exe with the bat file where I have the code which generates the aggregated .csv file.
  3. And at the end, I have 2 BeanShell Samplers which manipulates the .CSV file.

I tried to generate the aggregated csv file using both methods:

Code using cmdRunner:

```
java -jar "C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\lib\cmdrunner-2.2.jar" --tool Reporter --generate-csv "C:\LoadTesting\aggregate.csv" --input-jtl "C:\LoadTesting\log.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Code using JMeterPluginsCMD:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv "C:\LoadTesting\aggregate.csv" --input-jtl "C:\LoadTesting\log.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

When I run the .JMX file from command line like this:

```
jmeter -n -t "C:/LoadTesting/MyTest.jmx" -f -l "C:/LoadTesting /log.jtl" -j jmeter.log
```

The aggregate.csv file has only the header and the row with Total, but if I run one of the commands above the file is generated correctly.

Do you have any idea why my OS Process Sampler doesn’t work as I expect? 
Does anyone have a suggestion on what to check or how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can it be the problem with the extra space:

```
jmeter -n -t "C:/LoadTesting/MyTest.jmx" -f -l "C:/LoadTesting /log.jtl" -j jmeter.log
                                                              ^should this whitespace be here?
```

---

if not, most probably your OS Process Sampler fails somewhere somehow, you can temporarily [configure JMeter to save response data for failed (or even for all) samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter/) by adding the next properties to your startup script:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -n -t "C:/LoadTesting/MyTest.jmx" -f -l "C:/LoadTesting /log.jtl" -j jmeter.log
```

this way your `log.jtl` file will be in XML format but it will contain the output of the OS Process Sampler. If your Beanshell logic relies on CSV format you can use a Listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) instead

Other points:

1. Instead of waiting for log file to be complete you can set `jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush` property to `true` so JMeter would store results in the .jtl file as soon as they are ready/available
2. You can move your post-processing logic into [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating from Beanshell on next available opportunity (i.e. right now)